# Use of both parametric and non-parametric tests in the same study

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, parametric

Suppose we are investigating whether there is a significant difference in dependent variables A and B between two treatments in a population. Let's assume that the data provide parametric assumptions (e.g., normal distribution or homogeneity) for variable A, but not variable B. In this case, can we use a parametric test for A and a nonparametric test for B? Is it appropriate statistically if we present the data accordingly? Or should we evaluate both variables with multivariate normality, and use only one statistical test based on the multivariate normality? There are examples in the literature, and presented below. Actually, these are examples in demographic information. I could not find examples for analyzes between dependent and independent variables (First image from Wilkes et al. 2009, Fam Prac; second image from Fransen et al. 2003, Ann Rheum Dis).

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you explain how "data provide ... parametric assumptions"?  I thought that *people* provide assumptions!

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the comment. By assumptions I mean, for example, whether it can provide a normal distribution or homogeneity.